# What are the specifications for HTML5 audio.volume

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I've seem some code indicating that with javascript you can set the volume level of an HTML5 `<audio>` element using something like `document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1`, but I can't find anything to indicate what the volume range is? 0-5? 0-10? 0-100? Does anyone know what the max volume of an `audio` tag is, and what the smallest increments it can be raised in are?

Comment: I think the specifications may state that it goes from 0 to 10, but I'm pretty certain most implementations allow you to crank it up to 11 :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the w3c HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#effective-media-volume)

> ... 4. Let volume be the playback volume of the audio portions of the media element, in range 0.0 (silent) to 1.0 (loudest).

Comment: Thanks, not sure why i couldn't find it.